# Editing specific cells in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to scrape a table from wikipedia using the following code:

```
df_euro_cities_wiki=pd.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_European_cities_by_population_within_city_limits")[0]
wiki_dfdrop=df_euro_cities_wiki.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0', 'Date', '2011 Eurostatpopulation[1]', 'Image', 'Ref.'])
```

However when I scrape the table it includes the references.
[Table with references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ve4BF.png)

When I then try to edit these entries using code:

```
wiki_dfdrop.at['0', 'City'] = 'Istanbul'
wiki_dfdrop.at['1', 'City'] = 'Moscow'
wiki_dfdrop.at['0', 'Officialpopulation'] = '15,519,267'
```

Instead of editing the existing entries, it generates new ones at the end of the table.
[New entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQjX3.png)

What is the correct way to have a dataframe without references in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas apply map across all columns to split on `[` and select only to the left of '['

```
df_euro_cities_wiki=pd.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_European_cities_by_population_within_city_limits")[0]
wiki_dfdrop=df_euro_cities_wiki.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0', 'Date', '2011 Eurostatpopulation[1]', 'Image', 'Ref.'])

wiki_dfdrop = wiki_dfdrop.applymap(lambda x: str(x).split('[')[0])

>>print(wiki_dfdrop)

    City    Country             Officialpopulation  Location
0   Istanbul    Turkey          15,519,267          41°00′49″N 28°57′18″E / 41.013611°N 28.955°E
1   Moscow      Russia          12615279            55°45′00″N 37°37′00″E / 55.75°N 37.616667°E
2   London      United Kingdom  9126366             51°30′26″N 0°07′39″W / 51.507222°N 0.1275°W
.........
```

please note thet the resulting `Officialpopulation` column will be of 'string' datatype